# Nodejs installed without npm?

Tags: node.js, debian, npm

I've just installed nodejs on Debian 7 - by apt-get install nodejs.

Nodejs seems to be working fine, but when I enter "npm" I get "command not found".

"which nodejs" points to "usr/bin" and there it is - nodejs, but there is no npm file, what went wrong?

I found a few solutions, but all of them are related to Macs

BTW, "usr/local/bin" directory is empty I believe everything should install right there?

Answer (score 13):

You have several options.

If you want to continue using Debian packages, you could install `npm` (debian maintainers have it in a separate package).

`apt-get install npm`

If you want to just install `npm`, you can use this modification of Maxime's answer:

`curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`

(the `-L` is needed to make `curl` follow redirects.)

Finally, you may wish to use a different package source. 
For some Linux distributions (Debian/Ubuntu and RedHat/CentOS), the latest node version provided by the distribution may lag behind the stable version. [Here are instructions from NodeSource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) on getting the latest node, which includes `npm` and avoids using the problematic `nodejs` alias

Answer (score 8):

Install npm

```
curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

(the `-L` is needed to make curl follow redirects.)

and check version

```
npm -v
```

Comment: Ended up with errors: 
sh: line 1: html: No such file or directory
sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
'h: line 2: `<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
BTW, in what directory I should be when doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is easy to install in Linux

1. create a directory nodejs inside /usr/local/lib
2. download [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

   - move downloaded tar.xz file inside /usr/local/lib
   - extract the tar.xz file and rename as like node-v8.9.4
3. setup environment

   `cd ./etc/profile.d
   ls
   sudo touch nodejs-env.sh
   sudo atom nodejs-env.sh`

   where atom is my favourite editor; you can use your editor.
4. copy and paste below code inside nodejs-env.sh and save

   `export NODEJS_HOME=/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v8.9.4
   export PATH=$NODEJS_HOME/bin:$PATH`
5. restart you machine.
6. done

Answer (score 0):

There were several methods to install node.js on your debian. But I prefer this one:

Setup with Debian (as root):

```
apt-get install curl
curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
```

Then install with Debian (as root):

```
apt-get install --yes nodejs
```

After that, relaunch your terminal and type "npm" in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is due the need of super user rights during the installation. As others mentioned, you could do it via the `sudo` command and the manual installer.

Either way, there're several ways to install node in *unix platforms in a safer way without the need of super user rights using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (Node Version Manager).

Steps:

```
$ wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.25.4/install.sh | bash

$ nvm install 0.10
```

Also, you can find different [techniques to install node and npm without having to sudo](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814).

Comment: Please, consider about adding relevant informations from your links into your answer.